# Defining a harmonic function on an annulus with prescribed boundary values

Tags: complex-analysis

Give a harmonic function $u$ on the annulus $\frac12 \le z \le 2$ such that on the outer boundary circle $|z|=2$ the boundary-value function is $u(2e^{i \theta})= e^{i \theta}$, while on the inner boundary circle $|z|=\frac12$ the boundary-value function is $u ( \frac12 e^{i \theta} )=e^{- i \theta}$.

$\textbf{My Attempt:}$  We can express every harmonic function defined on $\frac12 \le z \le 2$ by $$u(z) = a_0 + b_0 log|z| + \sum_{0 \neq n \in \mathbb{Z}} (a_n z^n + b_n \overline{z}^n)$$ for constants $a_i$, $b_i$.

This question was on a complex analysis exam I took today. I am really curious as to the answer since I was not able to complete it.